# Intento terminar una secuencia de for en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

```
from collections import defaultdict

grafh=defaultdict(list)

v=[]

def addEdges(a,b):

    grafh[a].append(b)


def DFS(start,end):

    for x in grafh.items():
        print(x)
    print(start)
    v.append(start)
    ref=len(grafh[start])#get the number of children of the node
    DFS_ref(start,end,ref)

def DFS_ref(start,end,ref):

    global grafh
    i=0
    for i in range(ref):
            
        print("i"+str(i)+"-"+str(ref)+"-"+str(start))
        visit=grafh[start][i]
        print("--"+str(visit))

        if visit in v:
            print("e")
            continue
        if visit == end:
            print("entre")
            break
        else:
            #print(visit)
            print("-"+str(visit))
            v.append(visit)
            ref=len(grafh[visit])
            print(ref)
            DFS_ref(visit,end,ref)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    addEdges(6,4)
    addEdges(4,6)
    addEdges(4,3)
    addEdges(3,4)
    addEdges(3,2)
    addEdges(2,3)
    addEdges(4,5)
    addEdges(5,4)
    addEdges(2,1)
    addEdges(1,2)
    addEdges(2,5)
    addEdges(5,2)
    addEdges(5,1)
    addEdges(1,5)
    
    DFS(6,2)
```

intento realizar el algoritmo depth first search guiandome de la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

trato de hacer el recorrido de 6 a 2, el llega pero donde tengo el break para que termine el sigue.
agradecería mucho la ayuda

Comment: Estás haciendo llamadas recursivas a `DFS_ref`, o sea, tienes tantos bucles `for` como llamadas hayas hecho. Con un `break` sales del bucle más interno, pero no del los superiores. Intenta cambiar de estrategia. Sobre todo evita variables globales.

Answer (score 1):

El algoritmo se puede simplificar un poco.

El nucleo central queda asi: `depth_search` es un algoritmo recursivo que busca una ruta entre origen y destino.

Al entrar, primero chequea si ha llegado a destino. En caso contrario, el nodo origen no es el destino y es puesto en la lista de `visitados`. Esta lista se usa para evitar entrar en ciclos infinitos.

A continuación se recorren los hijos de este nodo origen, llamando recursivamente a la misma función con este nuevo origen.

El procedimiento se repite hasta llegar a destino o no encontrar el nodo buscado.

```
visitados = []
def depth_search(origen, destino):
    if origen != destino:
        visitados.append(origen)
        for nodo in grafh[origen]:
            if nodo not in visitados:
                if depth_search(nodo, destino):
                    return True

    return origen == destino
```

**Comprobación**

Vamos a poner a prueba el programa buscando los caminos desde el nodo 6 hasta todos los otros nodos.

Con todo, el programa queda asi:

```
from collections import defaultdict

grafh = defaultdict(list)

def addEdges(a, b):
    grafh[a].append(b)

visitados = []
def depth_search(origen, destino):
    """ Busqueda recursiva de un camino entre origen y destino.
    
    :param origen: Valor nodo de origen.
    :param destino: Valor nodo de destino
    :return: True si hay un camino. Visitados[] tiene el camino.
    """
    if origen != destino:
        visitados.append(origen)
        for nodo in grafh[origen]:
            if nodo not in visitados:
                if depth_search(nodo, destino):
                    return True

    return origen == destino


if __name__ == "__main__":
    addEdges(6, 4)
    addEdges(4, 6)
    addEdges(4, 3)
    addEdges(3, 4)
    addEdges(3, 2)
    addEdges(2, 3)
    addEdges(4, 5)
    addEdges(5, 4)
    addEdges(2, 1)
    addEdges(1, 2)
    addEdges(2, 5)
    addEdges(5, 2)
    addEdges(5, 1)
    addEdges(1, 5)

    for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
        depth_search(6, i)
        print("6->", i, visitados)
        visitados = []
```

produce:

```
6-> 1 [6, 4, 3, 2]
6-> 2 [6, 4, 3]
6-> 3 [6, 4]
6-> 4 [6]
6-> 5 [6, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Chequeo adicional. ¿Qué pasa si buscamos un nodo destino que no existe?

```
if depth_search(6, 7):
    print("6-> 7 ", visitados)
else:
    print("6-> 7 No encontrado")
```

produce:

```
6-> 7 No encontrado
```

Comment: waoo muchísimas gracias Candid Moe